# Открыть файл из проводника своим приложением

Tags: c#, wpf, файлы, реестр, explorer

Цель: передать путь к файлу от проводника Windows в свое приложение.
Я уже в курсе, что надо создать запись в реестре для ассоциации, и затем проводник будет передавать путь к файлу в программу. Как это сделать на WPF? Так же интересует как отловить несколько путей файлов.

Comment: _"передать путь к файлу ... создать запись в реестре для ассоциации"_ -- чтобы получить путь к файлу, создавать запись в реестре не нужно. просто используйте OpenFileDialog.

Comment: @Stack Вы не поняли, речь не о том как открыть файл в программе, OpenFileDialog я в программе вообще свой сделал, отдельный. Меня интересует как открыть файл в своей программе ИЗ проводника Windows, то есть по двойному щелчку по файлу определенного типа, и только потом запускается моя программа и открывает этот файл.

Comment: путь к файлу передается через StartupEventArgs. пример в моем ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ассоциация определенного расширения файла и приложения создается в системном реестре. Пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2069565/5673266).
Когда в Windows Explorer будет открыт ассоциированный файл, то запустится приложение и в нем можно получить путь к файлу так:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
     Startup="Application_Startup">
</Application>
```

---

```
void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
  if(e.Args.Length == 1) {
    var file = new FileInfo(e.Args[0]);
    if(file.Exists) {
       // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ох уж выручили, я уже и не ожидал что кто то ответит.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться классом `OpenFileDialog`.

```
public void OpenFile()
{
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

     // Открываем окно диалога с пользователем.
     if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
     {
         // Получаем расширение файла, выбранного пользователем.
         var extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog.FileName);

         // Проверяем есть ли в ОС программа, которая может открыть
         // файл с указанным расширением.
         if(HasRegisteredFileExstension(extension)) 
         {
            // Открываем файл. 
            Process.Start(openFileDialog.FileName);
         }
     }
}

// Проверяем есть ли в ОС программа, которая может открыть
// файл с указанным расширением.
private bool HasRegisteredFileExstension(string fileExstension)
{
     RegistryKey rkRoot = Registry.ClassesRoot;
     RegistryKey rkFileType = rkRoot.OpenSubKey(fileExstension);

     return rkFileType != null;
}
```

P.S. Если Вы хотите получить пути нескольких файлов, выбранных пользователем то можете воспользоваться свойством `OpenFileDialog.FileNames`. Далее аналогично примеру, можно их будет открыть.

Comment: Прочтите пожалуйста мой комментарий к выше(к моему же вопросу).

Comment: Возможно Вам поможет данное видео http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtYobuVvcFE